# "<Hangul> is undefined" error on space key press

Tags: key-bindings, error-handling

I'm running Emacs 26.1 without any "strange" configuration: a bare bone Ubuntu 19.04 emacs package with few packages installed from elpa or melpa.  I have the following issue: when pressing space bar I get `<Hangul> is undefined` error. This doesn't happen all the time, yet really often and in all modes I could try. `*Messages*` doesn't help as the same message is printed. I already had this issue with version 24.5.1 but I thought it was due to some outdated package.

This is really painful as you can't keep pressing space to repeat the (space) input and even worst, you can't define a macro with `C-x (` with spaces as the error cancels macro definition.

Comment: What keyboard layout are you using, and do you get the same issue when you use Emacs in a terminal?

Comment: The layout is French with a standard AZERTY keyboard. I don't seem to have this issue in a terminal but key repetition doesn't work. As I've been doing some additional tests, I just realized that `adoc-mode` seems to have no issue.

Comment: In that case, you might want to try switching to some commonly used keyboard layout like US English to check whether things work fine there, to ensure nothing else is the cause of the problem. One possible fix would be to change the space key to not be defined as some weird dead key.

Comment: I had the same issue. It turned out to be a hardware issue. See the following answer: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/70316/30537

Comment: @Dargscisyhp : This is exactly what is happening!! Thanks.