# How can I get holding down the spacebar to work as expected

Tags: debugging, keyboard-layout

When I am editing text, if I press and release the spacebar it works as expected. However, if I hold down the spacebar I get the following message in the echo area.

`<Hangul> is undefined`

I saw [this thread](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/51877/hangul-is-undefined-error-on-space-key-press), which suggested that it may be a keyboard layout issue.

`setxkbmap -query` in my terminal gives me

```
rules:      evdev
model:      pc105
layout:     us
```

I'm fairly new to Emacs and not sure what to try here?

I tried this with `emacs -Q` and the problem persisted. I'm using Emacs 27.1 with Linux Mint 19.2.

---

Adding some more information based on the comments.

1.) Starting Emacs as `env -u XMODIFIERS emacs` did not fix the issue.

2.) xev does detect spacebars as expected. Here is an example of the output

```
KeyPress event, serial 34, synthetic NO, window 0x2e00001,
    root 0x6c4, subw 0x0, time 2814496416, (-585,698), root:(379,718),
    state 0x10, keycode 65 (keysym 0x20, space), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 1 bytes: (20) " "
    XmbLookupString gives 1 bytes: (20) " "
    XFilterEvent returns: False
```

I noticed that the state goes to `0x0` after hitting numlock. I fired up Emacs and after hitting numlock the spacebar worked properly. However, it seems I need to hit numlock every time I start up Emacs.

I created the following file: `xkbcomp $DISPLAY my_keymap.xkb`. I found the following lines containing something Hangul related:

```
 <HNGL> = 130;
key <HNGL> {         [          Hangul ] };

 <HJCV> = 131;
key <HJCV> {         [    Hangul_Hanja ] };
```

Additionally, here are the modifier maps:

```
modifier_map Control { <LCTL> };
modifier_map Shift { <LFSH> };
modifier_map Shift { <RTSH> };
modifier_map Mod1 { <LALT> };
modifier_map Lock { <CAPS> };
modifier_map Mod2 { <NMLK> };
modifier_map Mod5 { <LVL3> };
modifier_map Control { <RCTL> };
modifier_map Mod1 { <RALT> };
modifier_map Mod4 { <LWIN> };
modifier_map Mod4 { <RWIN> };
modifier_map Mod5 { <MDSW> };
modifier_map Mod1 { <META> };
modifier_map Mod4 { <SUPR> };
modifier_map Mod4 { <HYPR> };
```

I'm still not sure why Emacs is reading Hangul anywhere, so I'm still lost. But at least I can hit numlock at the beginning.

3.) C-h k  brings up the following in Emacs:

```
SPC runs the command evil-forward-char (found in
evil-motion-state-map), which is an interactive compiled Lisp function
in ‘evil-commands.el’.

It is bound to <right>, SPC, l.

(evil-forward-char &optional COUNT CROSSLINES NOERROR)

Move cursor to the right by COUNT characters.
Movement is restricted to the current line unless CROSSLINES is non-nil.
If NOERROR is non-nil, don’t signal an error upon reaching the end
of the line or the buffer; just return nil.
```

Comment: Do you have the same problem if you start Emacs without your init file (`emacs -Q`)?

Comment: Yes, I should have mentioned this. I'll add that in to my OP.

Comment: Can you try starting Emacs as "$ env -u XMODIFIERS emacs"? See https://debbugs.gnu.org/db/19/19487.html . It's also good to include 3 other info: For the troublesome key (chord) (1) C-h k inside emacs (2) xev  outside (3) input method settings in between

Comment: Hi @Rusi, thanks for looking. I tried your first three suggestions, and edited the OP accordingly. However, I'm not sure what you mean by (3) input method settings in between. Thank you!

Comment: At shell what does $ echo $XMODIFIERS show? If it's set it (could be) your input method . Run a web search for (eg) xim uim fcitx ibus

Comment: `echo $XMODIFIERS`  did not return anything.

Comment: And what does emacs report for C-h k <Space long pressed>? (You probably already know more of this than I do eg xkbcomp has always been something outside my capacity )

Comment: C-h k <SPC long pressed> shows the same as the message I posted above.

Also, I know very little, xkbcomp is something someone else suggested I try, and I'm just posting it here. I do appreciate the help.

Comment: This (type of) q will find more expert answers at [unix](https://unix.stackexchange.com/) . I suggest u move it there. And if you just re-ask it appropriately reworded, mention here

Comment: @Rusi Thought you might be interested in knowing that a new (wired) keyboard fixed the issue.

Comment: Thtas an expensive heavy handed option! I wonder... If you (1) take your xkb map file which xkbcomp gives (2) delete the undesired hangul lines (3) compile to xkm as shown [here](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/SettingMetaWithXKB) and then (4) reapply that xkm (also in that link) ... What happens?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

sorry for kinda necro posting, but someone might find this useful. I stuck into Hangul_Hanja problem after installing emacs as well. After some research and conclusion, that's it's a hardware problem, I decided to look inside hardware. And voila. It is a hardware problem, because keyboard manufacturer didn't remove the rubber button beneath the spacebar which in fact is hangul_hanja key, and it naturally gets pressed when someone presses spacebar!!! After removing the rubber button from the hangul_hanja key hole, everything is working as expected.
[image: cheap keyboard with hangul keys]

Comment: What a fantastic and definitive answer! Thank you.