# Compose key method fails when the sequence following <Multi_key> is just a single character

Tags: input-method

I have noticed Emacs does not produce the desired key unsing the compose key input method when the sequence defining the key to be input is only a single character. The desired key is inserted everywhere else: browser, terminal, gedit, GVim, etc. Composition of two characters—such as `<Multi_key> <g> <a> : "α"`—does work in Emacs. (I use Arch Linux and in the example I used the syntax of the .XCompose file).

I've tested setting `.XCompose` as simply:

```
include "%L"
<Multi_key> <k> : "^"
<Multi_key> <Multi_key> :"^"
```

The first line does not work on emacs. The second does.  I am at loss as to why this happens and I would very much like to dedicate a few letters (giving up on the numerous combinations started by them) to make insertion of certain useful symbols more confortable.

Comment: What key is what you're calling `<Multi_key>`? What do you mean by `<g>` and `<a>`? Those look like Emacs function-key names, but I'm guessing you mean something else.

Comment: Oh. I wrote using the syntax of the .XCompose. In my case, `Caps Lock` is the composition key (called `<Multi_key>` at .XCompose). If I press it, and then `g`, and then `a`, the letter `α` is inserted.

Comment: Please put all such info in the question itself. Comments can be deleted at any time. Questions need to stand on their own. Thx.

Comment: This [comment thread](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/61436/how-can-i-get-holding-down-the-spacebar-to-work-as-expected#comment96730_61436) any use?

Comment: I'll give it a look.